# A testing feedback/report tool?

Tags: testing, projects-and-solutions

I'm thinking of developing a pluggable test and assessment module. This tool will be used especially for desktop application projects to report and log errors, bugs, missing features and suggestions from testers.

The tool will be plugged to the application by putting a small icon to the application itself. When pressed the tool will be visible where user can create entries about the application.

Is there already a tool like that? I am not speaking about UI testing btw.

For example, this tool might have a form consisting of

- Page name
- Environment information
- Entry type (can be bug, feature request, suggestion)
- Message
- User Info (name, contact etc)
- Date

I think such a tool can greatly help testers prepare reports. Developers can understand the issue better and track all the reports.

Comment: it sounds like a feedback gadget/pop-up with the data-elements/fields that are specified in your list, right?

Comment: Yes, the list can be customized ofcourse. The one in my post is just an example.

Comment: Then you would need something like jQuery Feedback pop-up, you may rename it and call Bug-Feedback - http://dumitruglavan.com/demo/jQuery-Feedback-Badge/demo.html

Comment: I don't think it can be made to work with desktop applications, right? I am looking a tool for desktop application and don't want to bother with anything external like a web browser but the idea is similar.

Comment: then better to provide more info regarding your development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have something similar built into our desktop products.

For logging errors/exceptions we use [Eurekalog](http://www.eurekalog.com/), which compiles into your exe file and can email you a stack trace and the exception type and message (among many other details). Highly recommended (or something similar depending on your language and development environment).

For feature suggestions we designed our own simple screen with similar fields to those you gave in your example and then email ourselves when the user clicks send.

Comment: Thank you. Even mentioning that you use a similar tool helps. I will have a look at the one you mentioned above.

Comment: @Mert - Let me know if you want me to expand on anything, though our "suggestion screen" is very simple since our clients tend to call or email us direct.